# Laravel Inertia Vue

Tags: laravel, vue.js, crud, inertiajs

I`m new to laravel and i try to do a crud tutorial but donesn t work the update method.

This is the controller

```
    public function update(UserRequest $request, User $user)
    {
        $avatar = $user->avatar;
        if(Request::file('avatar')){
            Storage::delete('public/'. $user->avatar);
            $avatar = Request::file('avatar')->store('users', 'public');
        }

        $validated = $request->validate([
            'username' => ['required', 'unique:users', 'max:255'],
            'name' => ['required', 'max:255'],
            'lastname' => ['required', 'max:255'],
            'email' => ['required', 'email', 'unique:users', 'max:50'],
            'role_id' => ['required'],
            'avatar' => $avatar,
        ]);

        $user->update($validated); 

        return Redirect::route('users.index');
    }
```

This is the view

```
const props = defineProps({
    user: Object,
    avatar: String,
});

const form = useForm({
    username: props.user.username,
    name: props.user.name,
    lastname: props.user.lastname,
    email: props.user.email,
    role_id: props.user.role_id,
    avatar: null,
});

function updateUser() {
  Inertia.post(`/dashboard/users/${props.user.id}`, {
  _method: 'put',
  username:form.username,
  name:form.name,
  lastname:form.lastname,
  email:form.email,
  role_id:form.role_id,
  avatar:form.avatar
});
}
</script>

                      <form @submit.prevent="updateUser">

                                <label for="username" class="block text-sm font-medium text-gray-700">Username <span class="text-red-600">*</span></label>
                                <input type="text" name="username" id="username" v-model="form.username" class="mt-1 block w-full rounded-md border-gray-300 shadow-sm focus:border-indigo-500 focus:ring-indigo-500 sm:text-sm" />


                          <div class="bg-gray-50 px-4 py-3 text-right sm:px-6">
                            <button type="submit" class="inline-flex justify-center rounded-md border border-transparent bg-green-600 py-2 px-4 text-sm font-medium text-white shadow-sm hover:bg-green-700 focus:outline-none focus:ring-2 focus:ring-indigo-500 focus:ring-offset-2">Save</button>
                          </div>

                      </form>
```

When i click save button nothing is happening. In the consol i don t have any error .

I try to modify the controller.

Comment: Why do you have the validation ```'avatar' => $avatar,``` ?

Answer (score 0):

Try `Inertia.put()` instead, since you sending it via `PUT` request. Also I think you can also use `form.put()` so that you don't to type the attributes again. just make sure that the `const form = useForm()`.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use the `Inertia.form()`.

```
 <script setup>
    import { Inertia } from '@inertiajs/inertia';

    const props = defineProps({
    user: Object,
    avatar: String,
    });

const form = Inertia.form({
    username: props.user.username,
    name: props.user.name,
    lastname: props.user.lastname,
    email: props.user.email,
    role_id: props.user.role_id,
    avatar: null,
});

function updateUser() {
  form.put(`/dashboard/users/${props.user.id}`, form)
}
</script>
```